# How can I expand a '#' in C++'s #define?

Tags: c++

I want to expose the private members when debuging, like this:

```
class A {
public:
  void f1();
#ifndef NDEBUG
public:
#else
private:
#endif
  void f2();
};
```

I want to use macros like:

```
#define PUBLIC public:
#define PRIVATE \
\#ifndef NDEBUG \
public: \
\#else \
private: \
\#endif
```

but, well, I know this won't work...

Is there anything that you guys recommend?? Thx in advance.

---

Edit 01:

My purpose is not to `debug` my code, but to test the private member functions.

Comment: I can't see why you would possibly want to do this because it will break the scoping rules.  How would it help by making something public?  Sure, you can call it from any routine but when you switch off the debug, your build just falls over.  Isn't it easier if you just learn how to use the debugger?

Comment: @cup I do know how to use debugger. When I'm doing tests, I also want to test the private functions, since it's not easy to locate the bugs if a public function that called a lot of private ones fails.

Comment: So basically, this is for unit testing.  Makes sense now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply define `PRIVATE` differently depending on `NDEBUG`:

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
#define PRIVATE public
#else
#define PRIVATE private
#endif
```

Comment: While you are at it, you may as well do the same for protected.

Answer (score 4):

You can't, the preprocessor doesn't have reflection. But you can do it the normal (ugh, arguably...) way:

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
#define PRIVATE public:
#else
#define PRIVATE private:
#end
```

Comment: So... that means that we cannot have #ifdef / #ifndef, etc. expanded in #define ?

Comment: If it is an arguable way, is there a better way of doing so or some other approach??

Comment: @Adam Generally, preprocessor hackage is evil. But I understand if you need this for debugging.

Comment: @Adam: You cannot have nested and scoped defines. It is unfortunate, but you cannot. I do not think they will address this any soon in the standard.

Comment: @LaszloPapp I understand that cpp is not supporting this, cause this will turn 'preprocess' from a string-replacing process into a code-parsing process.